# Why is there a difference in object position in 3D Viewport and VSE Preview?

Tags: 3d-view, video-sequence-editor

I have a scene with a rigged lego character.  The camera has a Background Image applied.  The lego man is positioned on the shelf of the race car bed.

[image: 3D Viewport]

[image: VSE]

In VSE, I've got a track with the still image.  On top of that, I have a full copy of the scene in overlay blend mode.

I would've thought the scene would line up perfectly, but as you can see, the lego man's position is off.

Any thoughts on why?  I've tried adding basic, un-rigged objects with transformations applied, but get the same result.  I'm stumped.

Comment: I may be on to something here.  In the VSE Sequencer Sidebar (N panel), in the Transform section, if I scale the Scene Strip to exactly 2.0, the lego man's position is exactly what I see in the 3D Viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  Figured it out.  I had my render resolution set to 50%.  So when adding the scene strip, I was adding my scene half size.